# Does cudaFree after asynchronous call work?

Tags: asynchronous, cuda

I want to ask whether calling to cudaFree after some asynchronous calls is valid? For example

```
int* dev_a;

// prepare dev_a...

// launch a kernel to process dev_a (asynchronously)

cudaFree(dev_a);
```

In this case, since kernel launch is asynchronous, when the cudaFree part is reached, the kernel may haven't finish running yet. Then will the cudaFree(dev_a) immediately after it destroy the data?

Comment: Pretty sure that `cudaFree` will synchronize before it attempts to deallocate the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Jared's comment, I am about 99% certain that the CUDA driver free/malloc pair are implemented as blocking calls which will synchronize the context on which they operate before they execute the call.

Comment: Thank you! How about the "free" function inside the kernel? If I have a kernel launch immediately proceeding it, does this work?

Answer (score 2):

CUDA now provide functions for asynchronous memory management based on streams: cudaMallocAsync, cudaMemcpyAsync, cudaMemcpyAsync.

A short introduction is available [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/enhancing-memory-allocation-with-new-cuda-11-2-features/)