# cuda and cub implementation of multiple k-selection

Tags: cuda, cub

I'm trying to implement multiple top-k selection in parallel, where each selection select k elements from a list of n elements and there m such tasks to be executed in parallel. I use cub to do that. I got a strange error and I don't know where I did wrong. I feel that I may made some obvious mistake in my understanding, can someone help me check?

EDIT:

I made it working by adding two `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` calls, before each of the two code section which contains `free()`. So now my question is, does `free` behaves differently than `cudaFree`, in that asynchronous calls immediately proceeding it is not allowed, as opposed to another question I asked here: [Does cudaFree after asynchronous call work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177568/does-cudafree-after-asynchronous-call-work)

```
// Assume dtop has size k x m and dmat has size n x m, where k < n
// Each column of dtop is supposed to obtain the top-k indices of 
// elements from the corresponding column in dmat.
template<typename ValueType, typename IndexType>
void TopKPerColumn_cub_test(DenseMatrix<IndexType, MemDev> dtop,
    DenseMatrix<ValueType, MemDev, Const> dmat);

template<typename T>
struct SelectLE {
  T x_;
  __device__ SelectLE(const T& x):x_(x){}
  __device__ bool operator() (const T& a) {
    return a > x_;
  }
};

template<typename ValueType, typename IndexType>
__global__ void k_TopKPerColumn_cub_test(DenseMatrix<IndexType, MemDev> dtop,
    DenseMatrix<ValueType, MemDev, Const> dmat) {
  int n = dmat.num_rows();
  int k = dtop.num_rows();

  cub::DoubleBuffer<ValueType> keys;
  keys.d_buffers[0] = reinterpret_cast<ValueType*>(
      malloc(sizeof(ValueType) * n));
  keys.d_buffers[1] = reinterpret_cast<ValueType*>(
      malloc(sizeof(ValueType) * n));
  memcpy(keys.d_buffers[keys.selector], dmat.get_col(blockIdx.x).data(),
      sizeof(ValueType) * n);

  void* temp_storage = 0;
  size_t temp_storage_size = 0;
  cub::DeviceRadixSort::SortKeysDescending(
      temp_storage, temp_storage_size, keys, n);
  temp_storage = malloc(temp_storage_size);
  cub::DeviceRadixSort::SortKeysDescending(
      temp_storage, temp_storage_size, keys, n);
  ValueType kth = keys.Current()[k-1];

  free(temp_storage);
  free(keys.d_buffers[0]);
  free(keys.d_buffers[1]);

  temp_storage = 0;
  temp_storage_size = 0;
  int* nb_selected = reinterpret_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int)));
  SelectLE<ValueType> selector(kth);

  cub::DeviceSelect::If(temp_storage, temp_storage_size,
      const_cast<ValueType*>(dmat.get_col(blockIdx.x).data()),
      dtop.get_col(blockIdx.x).data(),
      nb_selected, n, selector);
  temp_storage = malloc(temp_storage_size);
  cub::DeviceSelect::If(temp_storage, temp_storage_size,
      const_cast<ValueType*>(dmat.get_col(blockIdx.x).data()),
      dtop.get_col(blockIdx.x).data(),
      nb_selected, n, selector);

  free(nb_selected);
  free(temp_storage);
}

template<typename ValueType, typename IndexType>
void TopKPerColumn_cub_test(DenseMatrix<IndexType, MemDev> dtop,
    DenseMatrix<ValueType, MemDev, Const> dmat) {
  k_TopKPerColumn_cub_test<<<dtop.num_cols(), 1>>>(dtop, dmat);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm able to make it work, this implementation performs slower than single-threaded CPU code. I eventually implemented this with heap-sort and put the heap in shared memory. The performance is good.